# SAP DBTech JDBC: Cannot connect to jdbc:sap://192.168.33.114:39015/ [SAP DBTech JDBC: [2]: general error: SYSTEMDB not connected]

Tags: java, hana

**When i am connecting to my sap hana data base so its throwing below exception
but if i am not specifying any Database name then it connecting by default to HEX data base of sap hana.**

`com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: Cannot connect to jdbc:sap://192.168.33.114:39015/ [SAP DBTech JDBC: [2]: general error: SYSTEMDB not connected]`

Here is dummy code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class SapConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        Class.forName("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "jdbc:sap://192.168.33.114:39015/?databaseName=abcd";
        String user = "abc";
        String password = "xyz";

        Connection cn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        // ... do whatever with the results ...
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When connecting to a MDC tenant DB the port to connect against is not 30..15 but 30..13 as the connection goes against the `nameserver` process listening on the 30..13 port.

Changing your connection string to

```
String url = "jdbc:sap://192.168.33.114:39013/?databaseName=abcd";
```

should make it work.

**EDIT**

An alternative method to connect is to avoid providing the port numbers altogether and to let HANA figure these details out itself. Just providing the `instanceNumber` and the `databaseName` is sufficient in this case.

Example (DB runs on host `skullbox.lab.cat5`):

```
> java -jar ngdbc.jar -u <username>,<password> -n skullbox.lab.cat5 -d S20 -i 
20
Connected.
|                             |
-------------------------------
| 2017-08-15 17:04:53.0730000 |
1 rows.
```

The corresponding JDBC URL would look like this:

```
 jdbc:sap://skullbox.lab.cat5?databaseName=S20&instanceNumber=20
```

Comment: Thanks Lars..
but i got my solution. so i was trying to connect on wrong port, after reading Sap document founded that they are using 3__13/14/15/16.. ports for system data base, and for tenant data base they are using 3__40/41/42... ports and my DB was running on 39041 port.

Comment: Just added an alternative connection JDBC URL option that allows connecting without knowing or caring about the ports used.